# Django App to open github issues on server 500

Tags: django

I am working on a Django project and, so far, we are receiving e-mails when a **Server Error 500** happens in our backend. However, as we are a team of developers, we would like to open Github Issues instead of sending these e-mails. We have our project on Github of course.
I have been searching for an existing Django App that we could reuse but unfortunately I did not find any integrating such functionality.

Does anyone know if there is such Django application? The idea seems pretty simple and I am surprised i could not find any application available for this purpose.
Moreover, a [search](https://www.djangopackages.com/search/?q=github) on django packages does not show many results...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an off-topic question but [PyGithub](http://pygithub.github.io/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/Repository.html?highlight=create_issue#github.Repository.Repository.create_issue) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sorry, I did not know where to ask :(

Comment: A third-party service like [Opbeat](https://opbeat.com/) may well be what you want.

Comment: Try rollbar. It's has great error reporting and it's easy to add to django.